# Is there a way to pass multiple MIP starts to Gurobi?

Tags: gurobi

I was wondering if anybody knows if it is possible to set multiple feasible initial solutions in Gurobi MILP solver.

I already know how to set a single initial solution, as indicated [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples/mip_starts.html).

Answer (score 2):

From the APIs, you can supply multiple MIP starts using the [NumStart](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/numstart.html) attribute and [StartNumber](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/startnumber.html) parameter. E.g.:

```
model.NumStart = 2

# iterate over all MIP starts
for s in range(model.NumStart):
    # set StartNumber
    model.params.StartNumber = s

    # now set MIP start values using the Start attribute, e.g.:
    for v in model.getVars():
        v.Start = <value>
```

When using the command-line tool `gurobi_cl` you can use `InputFile` multiple times, e.g.

```
gurobi_cl InputFile=mipstart1.mst InputFile=mipstart2.mst model.mps
```

With both approaches, Gurobi will try all supplied MIP starts and use the best one.